# Surface Element for Triangle in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I'm currently working on a problem that asks me to verify Stoke's theorem. The issue I'm currently running into is calculating the **da**.

For Stoke's Theorem, $\int_V (\nabla \times r) \cdot da$, I currently have the value of $(\nabla \times r)$, and I just need to dot product it with each of the surfaces given by the shape below. I am trying to do this in spherical coordinates (and that is what my $(\nabla \times r)$ vector is in), but I can't figure out how one would go about getting the area element for a surface like the back triangle in spherical coordinates.

How are you supposed to approach these issues when there is no obvious way to deduce **da**?

[image: Triangle and Semicircle Face]

Comment: Could you provide some more context for the problem? Why are you preoccupied with expressing the area of the black triangle in spherical coordinates? For your reference this area element is $d\vec{a}=dydz \hat{x} = r d\theta dr (-\hat{\phi}) $. Are you a physics student or a math student?

Comment: Physics; the book requires us to use spherical coordinates (or cylindrical), but the book actually provides the surface area in spherical, I'm just not sure how they got it.

Comment: Would this book be Griffiths?

Comment: Yes, specifically problem 1.57.

Comment: Ok I thought so. Have your read the appendix on curvilinear coordinates yet? I now know how to write an appropriate answer, but I may not have time for a couple of days.

Comment: I have not, I will do that. As an aside, do you know any good resources for fortifying my knowledge on vector math? Specifically relating to curvilinear coordinates? I'm having a hard time with it and I've read a few sources but a lot of them seem to make assumptions, and I'm not sure where they get them from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68056/discussion-between-spencer-and-a4treok).